# Find text in files and get the needed content

Tags: linux, grep

I have many access_log files. This is a line from a file of them.

```
access_log.20111215:111.222.333.13 - - [15/Dec/2011:05:25:00 +0900] "GET /index.php?uid=01O9m5s23O0p&p=nutty&a=check_promotion&guid=ON HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://xxx.com/index.php?uid=xxx&p=mypage&a=index&sid=&fid=&rand=1681" "Something/2.0 qqq(xxx;yyy;zzz)" "-" "-" 0
```

How to extract the uid "01O9m5s23O0p" from the lines which have the occurence of "p=nutty&a=check_promotion" and output to a new file.

For example, The "output.txt" file should be:

```
01O9m5s23O0p
01O9m5s0999p
01O9m5s3249p
fFDSFewrew23
SOMETHINGzzz
...
```

I tried the:

```
grep "p=nutty&a=check_promotion" access* > using_grep.out
```

and

```
fgrep -o "p=nutty&a=check_promotion" access* > using_fgrep.out
```

but it prints whole line. I just want to get the uid.

**Summary:**

```
1) Find the lines which have "p=nutty&a=check_promotion"

2) Extract uid from those lines.

3) Print them to a file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do exactly that, in three stages:

(formatted to avoid the scroll)

```
grep 'p=nutty&a=check_promotion' access* \
| grep -o '[[:alnum:]]\{4\}m5s[[:alnum:]]\{4\}p' \
> output.txt
```

Comment: +1 for `-o`. But maybe it should be `grep -E -o 'uid=[^&]*' | cut -b5-` or something like that to catch the uid?

Comment: @Johnsyweb What if the uid has random format (alphanumeric too)? for example: uid=UREISDKS21323ZZZZZZZ

Comment: Then use awk, as @Jaypal suggested: `awk -F'[?&=]' '/p=nutty&a=check_promotion/ { print $3 }' access* > output.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If your lines which have `p=nutty&a=check_promotion` are similar in nature then we can set the delimiters and use `awk` to extract the uid and place them in a file.

```
awk -v FS="[?&=]" '
$0~/p=nutty&a=check_promotion/{ print $3 > "output_file"}' input_file
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
access_log.20111215:210.136.161.13 - - [15/Dec/2011:05:25:00 +0900] "GET /index.php?uid=01O9m5s23O0p&p=nutty&a=check_promotion&guid=ON HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://xxx.com/index.php?uid=xxx&p=mypage&a=index&sid=&fid=&rand=1681" "Something/2.0 qqq(xxx;yyy;zzz)" "-" "-" 0 
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[?&=]" '
$0~/p=nutty&a=check_promotion/{ print $3 > "output_file"}' input_file
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat output_file 
01O9m5s23O0p
```

Comment: +1: This is probably the best way to tackle this problem. You can shorten it to just `awk -F'[?&=]' '/p=nutty&a=check_promotion/ { print $3 }' access* > output.txt`.

Comment: True, I was initially a little skeptical because of so many delimiters I was more keen towards using `$0~/../` instead of `/../`. But I guess it works either ways. :)